# CDATA XML masking with XSLT should return same XML with few masked fields

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a requirement of masking few fields in XML of CDATA inside XML with XSLT.
So the resultant XML should be same like the input XML but few fileds are masked with XSLT.
I followed [this](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=42815) link which is masking as expected but producing XML is in different format.
I tried many other solutions from SO, they are almost outputing the new XML/HTML in other format which is different from the input XML.
Please check the following example for better understading.
  Input XML with CDATA content.

```
<XML>
  <LogLevel>info</LogLevel>
  <Content><![CDATA[ <Msg>
        <AccountNo>2701000098983</AccountNo>
        <ApplName>Testing</ApplName>
       </Msg>]]></Content>
  <Date>20140909</Date>
</XML>
```

Output XML should be:

```
   <XML>
      <LogLevel>info</LogLevel>
      <Content><![CDATA[ <Msg>
            <AccountNo>XXXXXXXXXX983</AccountNo>
            <ApplName>Testing</ApplName>
           </Msg>]]></Content>
      <Date>20140909</Date>
   </XML>
```

Edit:
I used the following XSLT

```
 <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(.,'&lt;AccountNo&gt;')">
                <!-- This is the CDATA that I want to mask and write back out as CDATA -->
                <xsl:variable name="tcontent">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="substring-after(substring-before(.,'&lt;/AccountNo&gt;'),'&lt;AccountNo&gt;') " />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[&lt;AccountNo&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="maskVariable">
                    <xsl:with-param name="tvar" select="$tcontent" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/AccountNo&gt;]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="maskVariable">
    <xsl:param name="tvar" />
    <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($tvar)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$length > 3">
            <xsl:value-of
                select="concat ('************', substring($tvar,$length - 1, 2))" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$length > 1">
                ***
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise />
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Output of using this XSLT is :

```
<LogLevel>info</LogLevel>
<Content><![CDATA[<AccountNo>************02</AccountNo>]]></Content>
<Date>20140909</Date>
```

Here in output, only masked output of  is displaying.
How to make other part of the code to get displayed ?
Please give me some idea how to do it ?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt and explain in what way the output is different from what you need. Note that `<Content><![CDATA[<Msg><AccountNo>XXXXXXXXXX983</AccountNo></Msg>]]></Content>` is the same thing as `<Content>&lt;Msg&gt;&lt;AccountNo&gt;XXXXXXXXXX983&lt;/AccountNo&gt;&lt;/Msg&gt;</Content>`. Producing the first variant will be more difficult.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I updated with the xslt and output what i get.. I tried some other ways as well.. but it seems i'm near to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Content">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'&lt;AccountNo&gt;')" />
        <xsl:text>&lt;AccountNo&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="acct-num" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'&lt;AccountNo&gt;'), '&lt;/AccountNo&gt;')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('************', substring($acct-num, string-length($acct-num) - 2))" />
        <xsl:text>&lt;/AccountNo&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'&lt;/AccountNo&gt;')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input, the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
   <LogLevel>info</LogLevel>
   <Content> &lt;Msg&gt;
        &lt;AccountNo&gt;************983&lt;/AccountNo&gt;
        &lt;ApplName&gt;Testing&lt;/ApplName&gt;
       &lt;/Msg&gt;</Content>
   <Date>20140909</Date>
</XML>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="Content"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Content">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="content">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'&lt;AccountNo&gt;')" />
            <xsl:text>&lt;AccountNo&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="acct-num" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'&lt;AccountNo&gt;'), '&lt;/AccountNo&gt;')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('************', substring($acct-num, string-length($acct-num) - 2))" />
            <xsl:text>&lt;/AccountNo&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'&lt;/AccountNo&gt;')" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
<LogLevel>info</LogLevel>
<Content><![CDATA[ <Msg>
        <AccountNo>************983</AccountNo>
        <ApplName>Testing</ApplName>
       </Msg>]]></Content>
<Date>20140909</Date>
</XML>
```

although this might not work with every processor (tested to work with Xalan 2.7.1: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMk).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. For simplicity only, i used two elements of `<Content>`, But the xml contains more than 25 elements in the `<Content>`.. is it the best approach to do ? or do we have any other option if we have to do this for more elements.. ?

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary I don't see what difference it makes, as long as `AccountNo` is the only data that needs masking. Note that there are **no** elements in the CDATA section; it's all just a string.

Comment: For parser it is just CDATA(Character Data), But for us it is an xml inside CDATA.. I agree that it is just a string whatever the data inside CDATA.
Thanks for your efforts and given a good solution. Thanks once again..

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside the CDATA section is XML disguised as text. XSLT is good at transforming XML, it's not so good at transforming text, especially text with a complex grammar. So my approach would be: extract the text from the outer XML document, parse it as XML, transform it using XSLT (real XSLT that works on nodes rather than on markup), serialize it back to text, then stuff the text back into the original (outer) XML document.

Raw XSLT 1.0 can't do this within a single stylesheet. You need the functions parse() and serialize() to turn lexical XML into a node tree, and back again. These are available as extensions in some processors (such as Saxon), they become available as standard functions in XPath 3.0, and they can be written as simple extension functions (e.g. in Javascript) code in most other processors.